# vsnprintf and NULL input string argument

Tags: c, string, printf, variadic-functions

What is the expected behavior of `vsnprintf` when it has an input NULL string and/or size=0, e.g.

```
vsnprintf(NULL, 0, "%d", p);
```

or

```
vsnprintf(NULL, 10, "%d", p);
```

Is it undefined behavior or valid scenario? It doesn't crash with both input string as `NULL` and its length as `0`, and returns -1 (the same for valid non-NULL string and zero length), however it does crash the other way around (`NULL` input string and positive length).

Comment: See [MSDN]( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1kt27hek(v=vs.110).aspx ) and as first argument should be non-NULL, this is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @t0mm13b are you sure about this?

Comment: @SouravGhosh OP was clearly asking what happens when NULL is passed in to the `vsnprintf` function, result after the call is undefined. You seem to think I was saying otherwise?

Comment: @t0mm13b any reference? For `C11`, please see my answer. (I think the presence of 0 and 10 also matters)

Comment: One is microsoft based, other is C11... cannot win eh..

Comment: Several things. 1) This applies to C99, not just C11. 2) The C standard allows an implementation to issue *any* diagnostic for *any* reason. 3) MSDN is not the C standard. 4) There's nothing on that page that suggests undefined behavior. Specifically saying "NULL invokes the invalid parameter handler" sounds like defined behavior to me.

Comment: actually OP, what compiler are you using?

Comment: @t0mm13b That page is pre-C++11, [see this more current docs.microsoft page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/vsnprintf-vsnprintf-vsnprintf-l-vsnwprintf-vsnwprintf-l?view=msvc-170), or [cplusplus.com](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/vsnprintf/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`vsnprintf(NULL, 0, "%d", p);` is actually defined behavior.

> 7.19.6.5/2 The `snprintf` function is equivalent to `fprintf`, except that the output is written into an array (specified by argument `s`)
>   rather than to a stream. If n is zero, nothing is written,and `s` may
>   be a null pointer. ...
>
> 7.19.6.12/2 The `vsnprintf` function is equivalent to `snprintf` ...

`vsnprintf(NULL, 10, "%d", p);` is not. Since `n` is not zero, you've violated a constraint and you got undefined behavior. Either way, you're likely writing to deference a NULL pointer which is again undefined behavior. If you're lucky your program crashes. If you're not, it'll keep running and do weird things to your program.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting C11, chapter §7.21.6.12, *The `vsnprintf` function*

> The `vsnprintf` function is equivalent to `snprintf`, with the variable argument list
>   replaced by `arg`, which shall have been initialized by the `va_start` macro (and possibly subsequent `va_arg` calls). [....]

and then, for `snprintf()`, §7.21.6.5

> [...] If `n` is zero, nothing is written, and `s` may be a null pointer.

So, your first case is defined, while the second case invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) by attempting to access an invalid (`NULL`) pointer.

Comment: `Concerning the return value of snprintf(), SUSv2 and C99 contradict each other: when snprintf() is called with size=0 then SUSv2 stipulates an unspecified return value less than 1, while C99 allows str to be NULL in this case, and gives the return value (as always) as the number of characters that would have been written in case the output string has been large enough.`

Comment: @EugeneSh. Still, I'll stick with the `C11`, _just as in the case of `fflush(stdin)`, in `C11` vs MSVC (you know)_. :)

Comment: Yeah, unless the *implementation* is breaking the standard.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Man pages, C libraries, and the specifications they conform to differ across systems. The C standard is the only authoritative specification. Anything else is up for grabs. In fact, I highly doubt we'd get the same text for `man 2 vsnprintf`. As an example, mine says `The snprintf() and vsnprintf() functions conform to C99.`